# Extract Frames from Video C#

Tags: c#, video, image-processing, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make an app that use the camera to record a video and process the images of the video. Here is what I want. First, my app records a 10 second video with Torch. Second, I use a method to playback the video to see what I record.

I'm stuck on three things.

1. How can I convert my video into individual frames (images)?
2. Is it possible to asynchronously convert the video while it is being recorded?
3. When I do convert the video into individual frames, how do I work with them? Are they JPEGs? Can I simply display them as images? Etc.

Main code:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App3
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{          
    DispatcherTimer D;
    double basetimer = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();       
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        D = new DispatcherTimer();      
        D.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        D.Tick += timer_Tick;
        txt.Text = basetimer.ToString();
        Play.IsEnabled = false;            
    }  
    public Library Library = new Library();
    public object PreviewImage { get; private set; }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        basetimer = basetimer - 1;
        txt.Text = basetimer.ToString();
        if (basetimer == 0)
        {
            D.Stop();               
            Preview.Source = null;
            Library.Stop();
            Record.IsEnabled = false;
            Play.IsEnabled = true;
            Clear.IsEnabled = true;
            if (Library._tc.Enabled)
            {
                Library._tc.Enabled = false;
            }                
        }
    }
    private void Record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (Library.Recording)
        {
            Preview.Source = null;
            Library.Stop();
            Record.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Video);                
        }
        else
        {
            basetimer = 11;
            D.Start();
            //D.Tick += timer_Tick;
            Display.Source = null;
            Library.Record(Preview);
            Record.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.VideoChat);
            Record.IsEnabled = false;
            Play.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
    private async void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        await Library.Play(Dispatcher, Display);
        //Extract_Image_From_Video(Library.buffer);            
    }
    private  void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Display.Source = null;            
        Record.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Video);
        txt.Text = "0";
        basetimer=  0;
        Play.IsEnabled = false;
        Record.IsEnabled =true;
        if (Library.capture != null)
        {
            D.Stop();
            Library.Recording = false;
            Preview.Source = null;               
            Library.capture.Dispose();
            Library.capture = null;
            basetimer = 11;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Library Class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.Devices;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Library
{

private const string videoFilename = "video.mp4";
private string filename;
public MediaCapture capture;
public InMemoryRandomAccessStream buffer;
public static bool Recording;
public TorchControl _tc;
public int basetimer  ;   
public async Task<bool> init()
{
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        buffer.Dispose();
    }
    buffer = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    if (capture != null)
    {
        capture.Dispose();
    }
    try
    {

        if (capture == null)
        {
            var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);               
            DeviceInformation cameraDevice =
            allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null &&
            x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
            capture = new MediaCapture();
            var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };
            // Initialize 
            try
            {
                await capture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
                var videoDev = capture.VideoDeviceController;
                _tc = videoDev.TorchControl;
                Recording = false;
                _tc.Enabled = false;                                      
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("UnauthorizedAccessExeption>>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception when initializing MediaCapture with {0}: {1}", cameraDevice.Id, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
            capture.Failed += (MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs) =>
        {
            Recording = false;
            _tc.Enabled = false;
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Code: {0}. {1}", errorEventArgs.Code, errorEventArgs.Message));
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
        throw;
    }
    return true;
}
public async void Record(CaptureElement preview)
{    
    await init();
    preview.Source = capture; 
    await capture.StartPreviewAsync();
    await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), buffer);
    if (Recording) throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot excute two records at the same time");
    Recording = true;
    _tc.Enabled = true;

}
public async void Stop()
{
    await capture.StopRecordAsync();
    Recording = false;
    _tc.Enabled = false;       
}    

public async Task Play(CoreDispatcher dispatcher, MediaElement playback)
{
    IRandomAccessStream video = buffer.CloneStream();

    if (video == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
    {
        StorageFile original = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        await original.DeleteAsync();
    }
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(videoFilename, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        filename = storageFile.Name;
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(video.GetInputStreamAt(0), fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            await video.FlushAsync();
            video.Dispose();
        }
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        playback.SetSource(stream, storageFile.FileType);
        playback.Play();





    });


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out just yesterday.

Here is full and easy to understand example with picking video file and saving snapshot in 1st second of video.

You can take parts that fits your project and change some of them (i.e. getting video resolution from camera)

**1) and 3)**

```
TimeSpan timeOfFrame = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

        //pick mp4 file
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        StorageFile pickedFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (pickedFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ///


        //Get video resolution
        List<string> encodingPropertiesToRetrieve = new List<string>();
        encodingPropertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Video.FrameHeight");
        encodingPropertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Video.FrameWidth");
        IDictionary<string, object> encodingProperties = await pickedFile.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(encodingPropertiesToRetrieve);
        uint frameHeight = (uint)encodingProperties["System.Video.FrameHeight"];
        uint frameWidth = (uint)encodingProperties["System.Video.FrameWidth"];
        ///


        //Use Windows.Media.Editing to get ImageStream
        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);
        var composition = new MediaComposition();
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);

        var imageStream = await composition.GetThumbnailAsync(timeOfFrame, (int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
        ///


        //generate bitmap 
        var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight);
        writableBitmap.SetSource(imageStream);


        //generate some random name for file in PicturesLibrary
        var saveAsTarget = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("IMG" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ".jpg");


        //get stream from bitmap
        Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
        await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

        using (var writeStream = await saveAsTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, writeStream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                (uint)writableBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)writableBitmap.PixelHeight,
                96,
                96,
                pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
```

If you want to display frames in xaml Image, you should use imageStream

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);

XAMLImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

If you want to extract more frames, there is also `composition.GetThumbnailsAsync`

**2)** Use your mediaCapture, when your timer is ticking

**EDIT**:

used includes:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.Editing;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

Comment: i think this will mot working .. my video will not picked from path , im recording on  stream video ,  `InMemoryRandomAccessStream buffer`  , is there a way to  convert  `InMemoryRandomAccessStream buffer` to `storegfile` then i can maybe use your way ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You have got MediaCapture object when in Record method, and obviously Storage file in Play method. What is not working?

Comment: If you want to use this in a standard .net desktop application, follow this steps https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Using-Windows-Runtime-in-a-.NET-desktop-application

Comment: To get videometa data one can use this instead in the code above
var props = await pickedFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
uint frameHeight = props.Height;
            uint frameWidth = props.Width;
            var videolength = props.Duration;

Comment: I cant include the Widows.Media.Editing.dll I found in the WIndows folder. VS says that it cant include it because its not a valid Assembly or COM. How exactly can I use the classes that were used here?

Comment: Really not sure where I'm supposed to get some of the libraries used for this answer. A suggestion would be to include the details about what libraries you're using here.

Comment: No special libraries need to be installed. This is a part of the UWP. You are probably not using UWP

Comment: it would help then if you showed the includes at the top of the file.  It doesn't matter what project type we use.  I've referenced vb assemblies and they work, with the proper include.

Comment: @JohnLord You have got it!

Answer (score 24):

I ended up using [MediaToolkit](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit) to solve a similar problem after having a ton of trouble with Accord.

I needed to save an image for every second of a video:

```
using (var engine = new Engine())
{
    var mp4 = new MediaFile { Filename = mp4FilePath };

    engine.GetMetadata(mp4);

    var i = 0;
    while (i < mp4.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds)
    {
        var options = new ConversionOptions { Seek = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i) };
        var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = string.Format("{0}\\image-{1}.jpeg", outputPath, i) };
        engine.GetThumbnail(mp4, outputFile, options);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone some day.

**UPDATE for .NET 5:**

Recently, I have needed to update this code to work in .NET 5. To do so, I am using [MediaToolkit.NetCore](https://github.com/mtebenev/MediaToolkit.NetCore), which has been in preview for over a year. Also note: you will need to make the latest ffmpeg, including all 3 .exe files (ffmpeg, ffplay, ffprobe) available to your app.

Without further ado, here is the updated code:

```
// _env is the injected IWebHostEnvironment
// _tempPath is temporary file storage
var ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "<path-to-ffmpeg.exe>");

var mediaToolkitService = MediaToolkitService.CreateInstance(ffmpegPath);
var metadataTask = new FfTaskGetMetadata(_tempFile);
var metadata = await mediaToolkitService.ExecuteAsync(metadataTask);

var i = 0;
while (i < metadata.Metadata.Streams.First().DurationTs)
{
    var outputFile = string.Format("{0}\\image-{1:0000}.jpeg", _imageDir, i);
    var thumbTask = new FfTaskSaveThumbnail(_tempFile, outputFile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i));
    _ = await mediaToolkitService.ExecuteAsync(thumbTask);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: definitely helped me! At the time this comment is made, the MedialToolkit nuget package does not support .NET core, works fine on .Net framework 4.8. @Brendan, there is a typo in your while loop condition, i believe your intended meaning is mp4.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds

Comment: This made extracting jpg's from a video EXTREMELY straightforward and easy. Thank you.

Comment: Thanx, mp4.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds worked for me.

Comment: This works great with seconds, however if I change the .NET 4.8 version (which I use) to milliseconds, nothing changes. Frames are still split every second. It is strange that mp4.Metadata.Duration.Seconds returns 18 and mp4.Metadata.Duration.MilliSeconds returns 20. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Joe, could it be returning just the milliseconds parts of the timestamp, not the total milliseconds? Also, as noted in the first comment, I should be using `TotalSeconds` - updated as of now.

Answer (score 8):

Use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) and install [Accord.Video.FFMPEG](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Video.FFMPEG)

```
using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
{
    vFReader.Open("video.mp4");
    for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bmpBaseOriginal = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();
    }
    vFReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: which wrapper have you used for ffmpeg in c#?

Comment: @MajidHojati This looks like Accord.net, which has now absorbed Aforge. One thing to note is that it is released under GPL.

Comment: Why do you use `Close` inside of `using`?

Comment: It works, but `FrameCount` is always 0 and video loops after the end. How can I check for the video end?

Comment: @Qwertiy I am getting FrameCount is zero. How did you fix this?

Comment: @Faeze, I've just ignored number of frames and wrote infinite loop. Haven't worked on it yet. Seems like we need to find other library. Please tell if you know some.

Comment: @Qwertiy, I wrote a loop that calls ReadVideoFrame() until the bitmap is null.

Comment: @Faeze, oooops... Seems my code ignores null, I have to try. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjAO.png

Comment: @Faeze, you are right, checking for null works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryorq.png.

Answer (score 0):

Another one way to get it :

I used [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore), official docker image with .net core 3.1 + ubuntu ([list of available images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/))

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-bionic
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libgdiplus

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YouConsoleAppNameHere.dll"]
```

**short code version:**

```
GlobalFFOptions.Configure(new FFOptions { BinaryFolder = "/usr/bin", TemporaryFilesFolder = "/tmp" }); //configuring ffmpeg location

string filePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "sample.mp4";    
FFMpegArguments.FromFileInput(filePath).OutputToFile("tmp/Video/Frame%05d.png", true, Options => { Options.WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.Png); }).ProcessSynchronously();
```

**extended version (with some console logs):**

```
using FFMpegCore;
using FFMpegCore.Enums;
...
GlobalFFOptions.Configure(new FFOptions { BinaryFolder = "/usr/bin", TemporaryFilesFolder = "/tmp" }); //configuring ffmpeg location

string filePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "sample.mp4";
Console.WriteLine(filePath) ;
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(filePath));


var mediaInfo = FFProbe.Analyse(filePath);
Console.WriteLine("mp4 duration : " + mediaInfo.Duration);

Directory.CreateDirectory("tmp");
Directory.CreateDirectory("tmp/Video");
Console.WriteLine("started " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

FFMpegArguments.FromFileInput(filePath).OutputToFile("tmp/Video/Frame%05d.png", true, Options => { Options.WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.Png); }).ProcessSynchronously();
Console.WriteLine("processed " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Directory.EnumerateFiles("tmp/Video/")));
```

As a result - png files will be extracted to tmp/Video folder. Of course, you can do the same without docker if you need.