# Zooming video in ScrollViewer - bad quality

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mediaelement

[image: Video vs image]

*Left:Zoomed in video (MediaElement). Right:Zoomed in picture. Same resolution. **Different quality**.*

I want to zoom video.

It is easy with `ScrollViewer` and `ZoomMode="true"`, but video is not zoom propertly (quality is worst). When I zoom snapshot from video, it is fine.

XAML code:

```
   <Grid>
        <!--Grid stuff-->

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <MediaElement Source="Assets/gopro4k.mp4"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <Image Source="Assets/gopro4k_00_00_03.jpg"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

What can I do with this?

Comment: How did you take the snapshot image?

Comment: @gbishop3 something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380868/extract-frames-from-video-c-sharp/35382071#35382071