# How to create a video editor Timeline with frames of the video in C# WinUI3

Tags: c#, user-interface, winui-3, video-editing

I am trying to create a WinUI3 app in C# a video editor i can do cut append and all those things but im trying to display the frames of the video in the time line thing like this [this is a sample of another project with timeline for video editing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg5qn.jpg) how to create for winui3 C#.

i am stuck havent been able to figure it out yet

Comment: This answer seems to show a way to extract frames from a video file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060721/2411960

Comment: i know how to extract frames im trying to create a timeline display on my ui which can be zoomed in and out which displays frames, audio, etc

Comment: This is too complicated for a single question. I would start by displaying the frames using an `ItemsRepeater` or an `ItemsControl` , then try to implement each feature one by one.

Comment: do you have a sample code for displaying frames on timeline

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any.